# Delete character out of string

Tags: c#, string, csv, io

I am having some problems with a quite easy task - i feel like im missing something very obvious here.

I have a .csv file which is semicolon seperated. In this file are several numbers that contain dots like "1.300" but there are also dates included like "2015.12.01". The task is to find and delete all dots but only those that are in numbers and **not** in dates. The dates and numbers are completely variable and never at the same position in the file.

My question now: What is the 'best' way to handle this problem?

From a programmers point of view: Is it a good solution to just split at every semilicon, count the dots and if there is only one dot, delete it? This is the only way to solve the problem i could think of by now.

---

Example source file:

```
2015.12.01;
13.100;
500;
1.200;
100;
```

Example result:

```
2015.12.01;
13100;
500;
1200;
100;
```

Comment: Can you have different dates formats in the file, for example YYYY.MM (without days)?

Comment: Sounds like you quite possibly want a regular expression...

Comment: This isn't deleting a character, this is parsing text. This is *not* an easy task. BTW *why* delete dots? They are perfectly valid separators. Are you having a *different* problem, eg trying to parse numbers using the wrong culture?

Comment: This could be a valid question @Pan if a large export has gone wrong and that file is only you have left.

Comment: you could try and parse strings to datetimes, if it fails, it's a number and you delete dot there

Comment: @PatrickHofman but the wrong solution if the OP wants to parse `13.100` to 13100. In fact, it's a common problem with ETL jobs and the fix is to determine and use the proper culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have to delete the dots because the numbers are needed without the dots in further processing. Just the dates (which are always YYYY.MM.DD can include dots.

Comment: @Lunatiic *why*? If you are using an Austrian locale (just one of the countries that uses `.` for grouping and date separator), you can parse numbers with `decimal.Parse("13.100",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-at"))` and get `13100`

Comment: Office programs (and Windows programs that respect locale settings) will export data using `;` as the list separator, `.` as the grouping separator and `,` as the decimal separator when run on locales that use these settings. Trying to replace the separators is risky and fragile.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It would be way too much to explain in here but to make it really short: The file is later processed by a special software which defines that the numbers are not allowed to have dots in them. I unfortunately didn't make the rules and i can't change that fact. I am using a german locale.

Comment: @Lunatiic you could change the locale used by the *exporting* program then eg to `en-gb`, or load the data as `de-at`, export as `en-gb`. Trying to parse just *some* fields requires some very precise regex. Eg `;\d+\.\d+;` wouldn't work with millions or decimals. You could try searching for `;(\d+)\.(\d{3});`, replace with `$1$2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source file looks like a valid file generated by a program running on a machine whose locale uses `.` as the thousand separator (most of Europe does) and date separator (German locales only I think). Such locales also use `;` as the list separator.

If the question was only how to parse such dates, numbers, the answer would be to pass the proper culture to the parse function, eg: `decimal.Parse("13.500",new CultureInfo("de-at"))` would return 13500. The actual issue though is that the data must be fed to another program that uses `.` as the decimal separator.

The safest option would be to change the locale used by the exporting program, eg change the thread CultureInfo if the exporter is a .NET program, the locale in an SSIS package etc, to a locale like `en-gb` to export with `.` and avoid the weird date format. This assumes that the next program in the pipeline doesn't use German for the date, English for numbers

Another option would be to load the text, parse the fields using the proper locale then export them in the format required by the next program.

Finally, a regular expression could be used to match only the numeric fields and remove the dot. This can be a bit tricky and depends on the actual contents.

For example `(\d+)\.(\d{3})` can be used to match numbers if there is only one thousand separator. This can fail if some text field contains similar values. Or `;(\d+)\.(\d{3});` could match only a full field, except the first and last fields, eg:

```
Regex.Replace("1.457;2016.12.30;13.000;1,50;2015.12.04;13.456",@";(\d+)\.(\d{3});",@"$1$2;")
```

produces :

```
1.457;2016.12.3013000;1,50;2015.12.04;13.456
```

A regular expression that would match either numbers between `;` or the first/last field could be

```
 (^|;)(\d+)\.(\d{3})(;|$)
```

This would produce `1457;2016.12.30;13000;1,50;2015.12.04;13456`, eg:

```
var data="1.457;2016.12.30;13.000;1,50;2015.12.04;13.456";

var pattern=@"(^|;)(\d+)\.(\d{3})(;|$)";
var replacement=@"$1$2$3$4";

var result= Regex.Replace(data,pattern,replacement);
```

The advantage of a regex over splitting and replacing strings is that it's a **lot** faster and more memory efficient. Instead of generating temporary strings for each split, manipulation, a Regex only calculates indexes in the source. A string object is generated *only* when you request the final text result. This results in far fewer allocations and garbage collections.

Even in medium-sized files this can result in 10x better performance

Answer (score 5):

If you can rely on the fact that dates have two dots and numbers just one, you can use that as a filter:

```
string s = "123.45";
if (s.Count(x => x == '.') == 1)
{
    s = s.Replace(".", null);
}
```

Comment: To improve performance it might be a good idea to check line length before counting how many dots are there (it should be exactly 12 characters for lines with date, assuming that format remains the same).

Comment: Good point @Fabjan. There are quite some possible improvements to make in this aspect.

Comment: I'm going to try out your solution after lunch. Thanks in advance @Fabjan The date format always remains yyyy.mm.dd

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on the number of dots as mistakes can be made.

You can use the `double.TryParse` to safely test if the string is a number

```
var data = "2015.12.01;13.100;500;1.200;100;";

var dataArray = data.Split(';');

foreach (var s in dataArray)
{
    double result;
    if(double.TryParse(s,out result))
        // implement your logic here
        Console.WriteLine(s.Replace(".",string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: That's just as likely to introduce bugs. `13.100` can be 13100 or 13.100 depending on the culture. `TryParse` will never fail, just return different results